# What to do with the grammar errors?

Tags: java, algorithm

I write a small program, but it was found several errors. I am confused and no idea why and how to fix it. Can anyone help me explain the errors and figure out how to make it work? [image]

Here are the codes :

---

```
class Solution {
    public int tribonacci(int n) {
        SearchQueue searchQueue = new SearchQueue();
        return searchQueue.count(n);
    }
}
class SearchQueue {
    private int theQueue = new int[38];
    theQueue[0] = 0;
    theQueue[1] = 1;
    theQueue[2] = 1;

    public int[] count(int n) {
        if (n == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        if (theQueue[n] != null) {
            return theQueue[n];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 38; i++) {
            theQueue[n] = count(n - 3) + count(n - 2) + count(n - 1);
        }

        return theQueue[n];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not the proper way to define an array.

It should be

`private int[] thequeue = new int[38];`

Also in your function you should return int instead of int[].